# Is there a way to use variable from outer function in the inner function body, in Python?

Tags: python, ironpython

The pattern of the code that I try to build is:

```
def OuterFunction():
    theVariable = 0

    def InnerFunction():
        # use theVariable from OuterFunction somehow

    # the solution is not to use InnerFunction(theVariable) due to the reasons given in the text
    InnerFunction()
```

My hopes were there is some keyword (like global) or a way to tell the interpreter to use theVariable from the outer method's scope.

Why I need it this way:
A Python script that we run before has to become module now (the collection of methods).

OuterFunction did not exist before and InnerFunction is just an example for a big number of very complex methods that bear an already existing logic.

theVariable is just an example for multiple global variables that were used in the script in all of methods that InnerFunction represents.

I do not want to change signatures of all methods, that are, by the way, nested.

EDIT:

Here is the code that crashes for me in every interpreter, with "local variable 'theVariable' referenced before assignment" error (so I could not just reference the variable):

```
def OuterFunction():

    theVariable = 5

    def InnerFunction():
        theVariable = theVariable + 1
        print(theVariable)

    InnerFunction()

OuterFunction()
```

EDIT2:

Seems trying to change the variable leads to the exception, which gives a wrong description.
If InnerFunction() is changed to contain only print(theVariable) statement it works.

Comment: In Python 3, you can use the `nonlocal` directive in `InnerFunction` if it needs to modify a variable of `OuterFunction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just reference the variable directly, as follows;

```
def outer():
    x = 1
    def inner():
        print(x + 2)
    inner()
outer()
```

Prints: `3`

Comment: it did not work for me. Can you check the example I have just added above, under label EDITED? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could simply reference the 'theVariable' inside the nested InnerFunction, if you don't want to pass it's value as a parameter:

```
def OuterFunction():
    # Declare the variable
    theVariable = 42

    def InnerFunction():
        # Just reference the 'theVariable', using it, manipulating it, etc...
        print(theVariable)

    # Call the InnerFunction inside the OuterFunction
    InnerFunction()

# Call the OuterFunction on Main
OuterFunction()

# It will print '42' as result
```

Comment: You are right. I have tried with online interpreters and it works. I do not know why IronPython 2.7 that we use throws exception "Local variable '...' referenced before assignment" . I will check.

Comment: @Срба You can't change it/update it, by the way. To do it, you have to declare it on the application "header" or "scope", and the set it as global.

Comment: I have just edited the text and added the very example where just referencing crashes. Do you know why, I really cannot see?
I think I could organize to pass with just viewing the variable, without editing.

Comment: Try adding nonlocal as directive to the 'theVariable'. I know that it will work in Python3, but let's try at least.

Comment: @GemanoLodi Aha, it does not crash if I do not try to change the variable. If InnerFunction contains only print statement, it passes. Interesting. Nonlocal crashes as IronPython 2.7 compiler does not recognize it.

Comment: @Срба On earlier Python versions it would happen too. Nonlocal directive helps a lot, actually... Could you organize the functions to edit the 'theVariable' just in it's main context?

Answer (score 0):

Would this be okay with you:

```
def OuterFunction():
    theVariable = 0
    def InnerFunction(value):
        return value + 1
    theVariable = InnerFunction(theVariable)
    return theVariable
```

This way you don't have to mess with scopes and your functions are *pure*.